# Labels in TableViewRow cut off (Titanium Studio)

Tags: ios, titanium, tableview, titanium-mobile

I have a problem with getting labels within a TableView to display correctly, and I hope someone can help.

Here is a screenshot of the problem: [image: table display problem]

The labels with the (...) behind them are cut off.
This problem does not occur when I set a fixed height to my rows, but since the text is of varying lengths, that's not a good solution for me.

I've tried the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664992/tableviewrow-height-in-titanium), but to no avail.

Here is my code to generate the table:

```
var aSection = Ti.UI.createTableViewSection({
    rows: [],
    headerView: header
});

for (var p = 0; p < answers.length; p++){
  var currentAnswer = answers[p]; 

  var arow = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
    selectedBackgroundColor:'#f5f5f5',
    answID: currentAnswer['aId'],
    map: currentAnswer['aMap'],
    isSelected: false,
    height: 'auto',
    rightImage: '/images/icons/radio-unselected.png'
  });

var atext = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    font:{fontSize:gui.defaultFontSize+2, fontFamily: gui.defaultFont},
    color: '#333',
    text: currentAnswer['aText'],
    left:10, top: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10,
    width:'auto',
    height: 'auto',
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderColor: "#000",
  });

  arow.add(atext);
  aSection.add(arow);
}

var sections = [];
sections[0] = aSection;

var answView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
  backgroundColor:'white',
  data: sections,
  bottom: 1,
  minRowHeight: 40,
});
```

I'm really at a loss with this. Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Ti.UI.SIZE` for both `height` and `width` instead of `auto`, `auto` has been deprecated a long time ago. Something like this would help you

```
var aSection = Ti.UI.createTableViewSection({
    rows: [],
    headerView: header
});

for (var p = 0; p < answers.length; p++){
  var currentAnswer = answers[p]; 

  var arow = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
    selectedBackgroundColor:'#f5f5f5',
    answID: currentAnswer['aId'],
    map: currentAnswer['aMap'],
    isSelected: false,
    height:Ti.UI.SIZE,
    rightImage: '/images/icons/radio-unselected.png'
  });

var atext = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    font:{fontSize:gui.defaultFontSize+2, fontFamily: gui.defaultFont},
    color: '#333',
    text: currentAnswer['aText'],
    left:10,  right: 10,
    width:Ti.UI.SIZE,
    height:Ti.UI.SIZE,
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderColor: "#000",
  });

  arow.add(atext);
  aSection.add(arow);
}

var sections = [];
sections[0] = aSection;

var answView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
  backgroundColor:'white',
  data: sections,
  bottom: 1,
  minRowHeight: 40,
});
```

Comment: I did this and while it's an improvment (the text now has line breaks), it's still cut off in some places.

Comment: Have you made the row size also Ti.UI.SIZE?

Comment: It worked after removing the "width" property on the label. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your text is too long then it overlaps the right side button but still you want to show full text then you should either set left & right or set width to Ti.UI.SIZE so If you want to overlaps right button then you should use Ti.UI.SIZE or not then you can set left & right

so in short, set width to Ti.UI.SIZE or set left and right property.

Answer (score 0):

Try using: `minimumFontSize:'18sp'`

Or some size that suits your display needs. This will shrink the font down to the minimum size to fit everything.